# Update: How to calculate date and time duration into Days in google shee? (excluding Sunday)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know it's basic but I'm new to this. I just want to know how can I calculate the days duration of the two dates?

For example, I have my start date and time **11/22/2021  15:20:43** and end date and time **11/23/2021 14:51:29** I want to calculate the total days from start to end date and time.
Also, If start date time column is BLANK, return to count of days including date today.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use the following formula: '=(C2-A2)'. This will give you the elapsed time between the two cells and display it as hours. You can take this calculation further by adding dates too. This is useful if you have work shifts that go more than 24 hours or that include two days within a single shift.

Comment: hi. I appreciate your response. But when I tried it, the outcome was inaccurate. Moreover, a blank column returns to a larger number or #na

Comment: ... and what would you expect to see on blank columns?

Comment: if start date and time is blank, result should return to blank @michelek

Answer (score 1):

Assuming start dates in column A and end dates in column B, you can try

```
={"Duration in Days"; Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A) * len(B2:B), datedif(A2:A, B2:B, "d"),))}
```

Change ranges to suit and see if that works?

**EXAMPLE**

[image]

---

REFERENCES:

- [DATEDIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055612?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

there is a `DAYS` formula exactly for that purpose:

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/DAYS(
 REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(B1:B), "(.|..)[\/\-\.](.|..)[\/\-\.](.+) (.*$)", "$2\/$1\/$3"), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A1:A), "(.|..)[\/\-\.](.|..)[\/\-\.](.+) (.*$)", "$2\/$1\/$3")))))
```

[image]

#### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N_rb7aGc897IzGxnrUA6xu6zc0f-GGz6TjBd9M-8V3E/edit#gid=0)

Comment: hi. thank you. tried this but blank columns returns to a larger number.

Comment: ... and what would you expect to see on blank columns?

Comment: @player0 sorry, how can I do that?

Comment: @naj answer updated